# Extracting a value from an integer

Tags: python, variables, extract

Say if I had the value 9010 in Python,
How could I extra the number 10 from 9000 then assign 10 to a variable, such as b = 10.

Cheers.

Comment: That is a several step process.  Consider treating it as a string, using string slicing to get the characters you want, converting it to a an integer again and assigning it at that point. Or, depending on your general use case, you could take the mod 9000 of the number...

Comment: What should `b` be if the value is 8023? What if the value is 10742?

Comment: It is pretty unclear what your use case is.  There are many answers, not all of which are suitable for all uses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to extract the last two digits of an integer:

```
n = 9010

int(str(n)[-2:])
=> 10
```

Using a similar idea you can extract any sequence of digits from a number, by first converting it to a string and then extract the required range of digits, by fiddling with the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from string operations for this:

```
>>> a = 9010
>>> 
>>> b = a % 100
>>> 
>>> b
10
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can see is to convert it to a string and extract the last two letters.
Like so:

```
a = 9010 # This is a integer.
b = str(a)[-2:] # str() converts to a string, and [-2:] returns the last two letters of the string.

b # Checking its value.
=> '10' # Now this is a string, if you want it to be a integer use the int() function.

b = int(b) # The old value of b is converted into an integer and saved back into b.
b # Checking its new value.
=> 10 # b is now an integer.
```

b would then be the string '10'. So use it as a integer, simply convert it by using the int() function. For example int(b)